# how to execute a class with some condition statements in python?

Tags: python, oop

#Making a program "(subscribing for an entertainment)like Netflix" that would ask for users name then age.before they enter they should be on a legal age then if not print ("sorry you are not allowed to have a subscription").
If not. The code will continue then will ask for the users for their amount of money  that they will pay  and the higher the money the higher the discount price. Then will also asked how many months they will subscribe for the entertainment restricted (1,3,6,12 only) else the program will stop.

```py
class Entertainment:
    def __init__(self, subscription, price, term):

        self.subscription = subscription

        self.price = price

        self.term = term

    nameUser = input("Your name is,")

    ageUser = int(input("Age:"))

    if ageUser < 13:
        return total_amount

    subscription = float(input("Money Available: "))

    if subscription <= 100:
        price = subscription - 0.5

    elif subscription in range(101 - 200):
        price = subscription - 0.10

    elif subscription in range(201 - 300):
        price = subscription - 0.15

    elif subscription >= 400:
        price = subscription - 0.20

    def MonthlySubs():
        # Making this strictly 1,3,6,12 only and other numbers will not be accepted
        use_months = float(input("(1,3,6,12) Only "))
        if use_months == 1:
            return price / 1

        elif use_months == 3:
            return price / 3

        elif use_months == 6:
            return price / 6

        elif use_months == 12:
            return price / 12

        else:
            print("Invalid Months of subscription")
            break
```

#MAKING SOMETHING LIKE HOW PEOPLE SUBSCRIBE FOR PREMIUM BENEFITS
#problem is I don't understand how I will make these conditions connect to become a whole program
# Help me how I will have an output like this using classes:
>#Name: Mitchel
> #Age: 21
> #Money: 200
> #subscription months = 3
> #your payment amount is  209.5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to be confusing classes with functions to some extent. You can't return from a `class` statement, and you typically don't put this much code in the body of a class statement. Whatever you *do* put in the `class` statement is used to define class attributes; you almost never do things like ask for user input. You might want to read through [the tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) first.

Comment: Currently working on it. I appreciate the link.